# Method required by interface not met by extension method

Tags: flutter, dart, interface, abstract-class

For an education app I'm building, I have a module interface that requires a `copyWith` method:

```dart
abstract class Module {
  // ...
  Module copyWith() => throw 'You should call the instance\'s copyWith.';
}
```

The problem is that I'm using a codegen package that [generates the copyWith](https://pub.dev/packages/copy_with_extension) method on an extension for the module subclasses:

```dart
part 'audio_module.g.dart';

@immutable
@CopyWith()
class AudioModule implements Module {
  /* ... */
}
```

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of audio_module;

// **************************************************************************
// CopyWithGenerator
// **************************************************************************

extension AudioModuleCopyWithExtension on AudioModule {
  AudioModule copyWith(/* ... */) {
    return AudioModule(/* ... */);
  }
}
```

On my `AudioModule` class I'm thus getting this error because I think it's not counting extension method:

```
Missing concrete implementation of 'Module.copyWith'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.
```

Why is this happening if the subclass (in one way or another) does implements the `copyWith`?

Thank you

## Edit

The workaround I ended up using was to instead use the [functional_data code gen package](https://pub.dev/packages/functional_data) which builds a class with the copyWith method on it that you then extend. No extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extension method, your class `AudioModule` does not implement/override the abstracte method in `Module`. Extension methods work like static methods under the hood, so it does not really add `copyWith()` to `AudioModule`.

Just have a look at the Dart docs or google for Dart extension methods and conflict resolution.